# Player Jumping Very High Every Few Jumps

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm making a 2d platformer and every few jumps the player jumps very high but most jumps it is a normal height how do I fix this? My best idea is that it is the deactivated platform getting in the way but I am very stumped and I have no idea how I could fix this

Video Of It Happening: https://youtu.be/9F0BplXUTKc

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speedright = 30;
    public GameObject player;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speedleft = -100;
    public Text e;
    Scene currentScene;
    string sceneName;
    public float jumpheight = 115;
    public Talking script;
    bool isJumping;
    public Text h;
    public float hp = 100;
    public GameObject playerbody;
    public Animator anim;
    public Rigidbody2D bg;
    public float bgspeedright = -1.5f;
    public float bgspeedleft = 1.5f;
    bool cjump = false;
    public float Health = 100;
    public float Count;
    public string Scene2;

    void Start()
    {
        Count = 0;
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;
        script.CanMove = 1;
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        if (sceneName == "Bedroom"){
            e.text = "E To Interact";
            e.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Hallway");
            }
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Health = script.Health;
        bgspeedright = -0.9f;
        bgspeedleft = 0.9f;
        if (sceneName == "Butterland")
        {
            h.text = $"Health: {Health}";
        }
        jumpheight = 80;
        if (Health <= 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("DIE");
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Death");
        }

        if (Count == 5 || Count > 5)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("You Cheater!");
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Cheater Detection"))
        {
            InvokeRepeating("Counter", 1, 1);
        }

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Floor"))
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Platform"))
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Floor") && script.floordanger == true)
        {
            Health = 0;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        CancelInvoke("Counter");
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (script.CanMove == 1)
        {

            if (Input.GetKey("d"))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(speedright, rb.velocity.y);
                rb.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                bg.velocity = new Vector2(bgspeedright, bg.velocity.y);
            }

            if (Input.GetKey("a"))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(speedleft, rb.velocity.y);
                bg.velocity = new Vector2(bgspeedleft, bg.velocity.y);
                rb.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
            }

            if (!Input.GetKey("a") && !Input.GetKey("d"))
            {
                bg.velocity = new Vector2(0, bg.velocity.y);
            }

            if (Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("d"))
            {
                anim.SetBool("IsWalking", true);
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyUp("d"))
            {
                anim.SetBool("IsWalking_Right", false);
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyUp("a"))
            {
                anim.SetBool("IsWalking", false);
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isJumping == false)
            {
                rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpheight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                cjump = true;
                if(cjump == true)
                {
                    Invoke("CJump", 0.012f);
                }
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                speedleft = -15;
                speedright = 15;
            }

            if (!Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                speedleft = -10;
                speedright = 10;
            }
        }
    }

    void CJump()
    {
        isJumping = true;
        cjump = false;
    }

    void Counter()
    {
        Count = Count + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code and monitored the jump height?

Comment: Yes I've checked the jump height and tried over a week trying to debug the code that's why I'm here

Comment: Where did you take an idea to place input analysis into the FixedUpdate method? Seriously, it seems that someone posted some guide, as this is not the first time I see this.

Comment: you're doing input handling in `FixedUpdate`. This is a bad idea which can lead to undesired behaviour. In this instance however I think the whole cjump Invoke stuff could be the issue. My best guess is that you whole jumping logic is called twice before your `Invoke("CJump",0.012f) call goes trough, meaning you're adding your jump force twice in some instances. 
Try to restructure the whole script and separate input handling from physics handling.
[Brackeys has a really good beginners guide covering the topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwcT-Dch0bA)

Comment: I think I meant to make the input go in update and force be applied in update so I might of mixed it up I don't really remember

Comment: Generally speaking you want to handle input in `Update` and handle physics-related stuff in `FixedUpdate`.
Also try to avoid using `Invoke` in general, since it promotes relying on delays that might not necessarlily be accurate enough.
I have never had a instance where a `Invoke`-call was a good solution, now that I'm thinking about it...

Comment: @Nicolas I remvoed the c jump and put it in update but it  still itsn't working

Comment: I can't help you debugging your script step by step. If you're a complete beginner I highly suggest you watch the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwcT-Dch0bA) I linked above. It basically guides you through creating a 2d platformer controller from scratch and teaches you about good practices while doing so.
No offense, but your script is messy and has other issues. There's no guarantee that what I suggested works without other modifications, as you just found out. Spend the time and learn good practices, be patient and it will work at some point.

Comment: Btw did you follow a guide?

Comment: No I did not use a guide guides do not let you learn

Comment: You should absolutely follow a guide and learn from people who know what they are doing. As long as you're not just blindly copy-pasting someone else's code you're always going to learn something by listening to people who know more than you do.

Comment: I have followed guides before many times I am not new to programming and game development, I already know how to code.

Comment: If you say so...